# How to create a custom Linux distro that runs just one program and nothing else?

Tags: linux, distributions

How I could go about creating my own "custom" Linux distro that will run just one program, pretty much exactly the same way as [XBMCbuntu](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=XBMCbuntu).

Comment: Welcome on U&L, please take a [guided tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and take the time to learn [how to ask a question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) what do you want to do ? because the definition of application is pretty vague and does not mean nothing at all, because my advise would be to use `busybox` but that's probably not what you want. so please, take the necessary time to express your need and we might be able to help you. Do not hesitate to **[edit]** your question to add  any relevant element in it.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me...

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' well no, because I bet you can still have access to a terminal or something similar on XBMCubuntu while it seems only one app is running graphically,but notonly one app is running.  I have made a small distro once from scratch with only a kernel and busybox, in that case, even if there is services that are launch by the kernel, you can say busybox is your only app.

Comment: @Kiwi That's a good answer then (better than LFS). Keep in mind: 1) This question may be useful to other people whose general purpose is the same, so a range of answers is good, 2) While there is a range of possible solutions here -- i.e. [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) -- and some *may* be better suited to some more specific goal than others, I am pretty sure they *will all work* and a significant aspect of deciding on a solution will be subjective (e.g., because of the OP's prior knowledge and experience, *not* the objective nature of the task).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not start messing with LFS, that is a garden path leading to some dark woods.

Start with a distro where you have a lot of control over the initial install, such as Arch, or a headless edition such as Ubuntu server.  The point of this is not so much to save space as to delimit the complexity of the init configuration; starting from a headless distro, if the application you want to run requires a GUI, you can add what's required for that without having to end up with a GUI login (aka. the display manager or DM) started by init, and a fullblown desktop environment to go with it.

You then want to learn how to configure [the init system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) to your purposes -- note that you cannot do without init, and it may be the best means of accomplishing your goal.  The init system used on most linux distros now is [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

The point here is to minimize what init does at boot, and that is how you can create a system that will run a minimal amount of software to support the application you want to focus on -- this is essentially how a server is set up, BTW, so it is a common task (note that you can't literally have "just one" userland process running, at least not usefully).

If the application you want to run is a GUI program (a good example of why you can't literally just run one application, since GUI apps require an X server), you can have an `~/.xinitrc` that looks like this;

```
#!/bin/sh

myprogram
```

When you then `startx`, your program will be the only thing running, and it will be impossible to change desktops or start anything else, partially because there is no window manager or desktop environment (hence, there will be no window frame or titlebar either).

Comment: You can't do without `init` but certainly you can do without `upstart, systemd,` or `sysv. init` is just some executable file named `init` that your kernel invokes when it mounts `initramfs.` In most cases these other three aren't even `init` but they're actually `exec`ed into by `init,` which is commonly `busybox.`

Comment: @mikeserv Absolutely (and I did explicitly mention that these are not the only three choices).  Note also that I deliberately excluded `busybox` because that deserves separate treatment in a separate answer, but not by me.

Comment: How gracious of you to offer! But no damn way.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this approach actually works in practice. Anyone actually tried it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha If you mean what I'm recommending here (customize the init configuration), of course it does -- that's how the system already works, you'd just be producing a stripped down and simplified version (I'm sure this is what XBMCbutu is).  If you mean, replacing init with some more specialized executable ala busybox, it's probably more trouble than it's worth unless you *must* do it that way -- the main purpose of busybox is for use in tiny embedded environments (with, e.g., only a few MB of RAM).

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' : I meant the whole process you describe above.

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused but I have to ask this question to make your answer clearer for myself: Can I use this solution to remaster a Distribution this way and turn it into an ISO so that when installed, it will have a package of mine pre-installed on it (after installation)? (Yes I have tried available remaster tools already, but each of them had their own weaknesses). __EDIT:__ For instance, say I have a file named foo.deb, can I edit a Debian ISO and include this new deb package in it and get another ISO as the output for future installations?

Comment: Minor nitpick: I wouldn't put it that way ("remaster a distribution"); a distibution is more than just an image.  But yes, you can mount, edit, (even run) and re-save OS images with permanent changes.  "ISO" is really a format specific to CDs/DVDs, although it is commonly misused to refer to device images generally.

Answer (score 30):

**Minimal init hello world program step-by-step**

[image]

Compile a hello world without any dependencies that ends in an infinite loop. `init.S`:

```
.global _start
_start:
    mov $1, %rax
    mov $1, %rdi
    mov $message, %rsi
    mov $message_len, %rdx
    syscall
    jmp .
    message: .ascii "FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR\n"
    .equ message_len, . - message
```

We cannot use the exit system call, or else the kernel panics, the only way to exit gracefully from the init is to [poweroff the machine with the `reboot` syscall](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/4f82f79be7b0717c12924f4c9b7c4f46f8f18e2f/userland/linux/poweroff.c#L8).

Then:

```
mkdir d
as --64 -o init.o init.S # assemble
ld -o d/init init.o      # link
cd d
find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip > ../rootfs.cpio.gz
ROOTFS_PATH="$(pwd)/../rootfs.cpio.gz"
```

This creates a filesystem with our hello world at `/init`, which is the first userland program that the kernel will run. We could also have added more files to `d/` and they would be accessible from the `/init` program when the kernel runs.

Then `cd` into the Linux kernel tree, build is as usual, and run it in QEMU:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
cd linux
git checkout v4.9
make mrproper
make defconfig
make -j"$(nproc)"
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd "$ROOTFS_PATH"
```

And you should see a line:

```
FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR
```

on the emulator screen! Note that it is not the last line, so you have to look a bit further up.

You can also use C programs if you link them statically:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR\n");
    sleep(0xFFFFFFFF);
    return 0;
}
```

with:

```
gcc -static init.c -o init
```

Dynamic linking would require setting up a the dynamic linker executable, the most common of which are part of C standard libraries like glibc.

You can run on real hardware with a USB on `/dev/sdX` and:

```
make isoimage FDINITRD="$ROOTFS_PATH"
sudo dd if=arch/x86/boot/image.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Great source on this subject: [Tech Tip: How to use initramfs | landley.net](http://landley.net/writing/rootfs-howto.html) It also explains how to use `gen_initramfs_list.sh`, which is a script from the Linux kernel source tree to help automate the process.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.10, QEMU 2.6.1.

**Next steps**

The next thing you want to do, is to setup [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox), see also: [What is the smallest possible Linux implementation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/what-is-the-smallest-possible-linux-implementation/203902#203902)

BusyBox implements basic POSIX-y CLI utilities, including a POSIX-y shell, which you allow you to more easily experiment with the system interactively.

Personally, at this point I prefer to just rely on [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org), which is an amazing set of scripts that automates building everything from source and making the root filesystem.

I have uploaded a highly detailed and automated helper for that at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat

Comment: This is probably the most underrated answer here :D.  Awesome!

Comment: @msouth a little less so now :-)

Comment: As usual Ciro - excellent advice and imho, the best answer by far.

Answer (score 2):

if you are little bit in programming and you want create it from scratch you can go with LFS i.e. Linux from Scratch http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

if you want to customize ubutnu you can use ubunt-builder and if you want it on rpm base you can use SUsE-Studio,Suse studio will allow you to make custom suse linux

cheers

Answer (score 2):

It is more about what your "one program" requires.

You can still have a good start of understand how to put things together by building an [LFS (aka "**Linux From Scratch**")](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) .
Then you will add things required by your program or go for a full distribution because building heavy sub-system like *Gnome* or *KDE* on LFS can be a real pain-in-the-ass.

Of course going backward may be easier at first, but removing things from a full distrib can be troublesome: do this in a VM and do copy of this VM at every step.

(my 2 cents)

**Edit**:

As pointed out by *SecurityBeast* instead of starting from a full distribution like *CentOS* or *Ubuntu*, you may also have a look at building distribution tools like:

- [Ubuntu-builder](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder)
- [SUSE Studio](https://susestudio.com/)
- [Instalinux](http://www.instalinux.com/)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to ask is what does your "one program" need and what resources do you have.

If it needs a wide selection of libraries and support binaries you may be best off using a "regular" linux distro (Debian or similar) and just messing with the boot process a bit.

If it needs a narrower selection of support stuff but still requires stuff like networking or support for a variety of hardware using different kernel modules or userland support bits and you don't want the disk space overhead of a regular distro then I would suggest looking at embedded distros (buildroot or similar) or maybe a linux from scratch approach (though that can be a maintainance headache)

If you need just what a non-modular kernel can provide and nothing else then running your own binary straight on the kernel may work and be the lightest soloution..